# Filter a pandas DataFrame based on a boolean series with Date index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a large df where the indices are dates and a boolean (True/False) series where the indices are dates as well. They do not contain the same number of rows. I want to subset my df by date where the corresponding series value is True. I have two ways of achieving this which work but I feel like there are better approaches. One involves looping and the other is basically this:

```
df[df.index.isin(df_sub_look[df_sub_look == True].index)]
```

I feel like there must be other ways and so I'm curious if there is another straightforward method that I have overlooked.

Comment: Having a sample dataframe would be very helpful...

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, join on the Date index, and then filter:

```
df = df_sub_look.to_frame(name='sub_look').join(df)
df[df.pop('sub_look')]
```

Comment: interesting. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @ChaseCB I'd also like to know whether it works for you as intended.

Comment: it does indeed.